# Can I install DDR3 1333 RAM into a motherboard that supports DDR3 2200?

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, ddr3

Can I install DDR3 1333 MHz RAM into a motherboard that supports DDR3 2200 RAM?

I think it should be acceptable, but don't want to risk the investment I've already made on the motherboard

For anybody who needs specifics, the motherboard here is [P7P55D-E PRO](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=T2FxW2fXGZQgSn2V)

Comment: ok, just saw the manual says 1333 is good. How do I propose the question be closed?

Comment: You still can't. Anyway, there's no reason to close. Post you comment as an answer and accept it in two days. It's perfectly OK to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=T2FxW2fXGZQgSn2V) for the said motherboard, I understand DDR3 1333/1600 are both acceptable