# RAM speed support by motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

If a motherboard support the RAM speeds 3000/3200/3600, Could you use RAM with 3300 speed and the motherboard would adjust it or just accept it, or would it reject it?

Comment: If your motherboards supports RAM at those discrete speeds, I would expect that if you installed 3300 speed RAM, it would run at 3200.

Comment: Correct, it clocks back to the nearest lower speed automatically unless your bios can do manual overclocking of memory which is not recommended.

Comment: I liked this question for being simple and straightforward, but this has been asked in the [recent](http://superuser.com/q/917497/109256), [older](http://superuser.com/q/775864/109256) and [oldest](http://superuser.com/q/263077/109256) posts I have found. Not sure how to deal with this kind of similarly repeated questions.